# Why use Flask's app.test_client() over requests.Session() for testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

If `requests.Session()` can handle cookies and does almost everything that `app.test_client()` does. Then why use the `app.test_client()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit of digging around, I think I found a good reason to use `app.test_client()` as well as some other context managers that are provided by Flask.

### Test Client

`app.test_client()`

Enables you to access local contexts via its context manager
This is extremely helpful when trying to access variables on the `_request_ctx_stack` ([request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/) stack). e.g. the `request` and `session` context locals.

Some extensions also store variables on the `_request_ctx_stack`. e.g. [flask_login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) stores the `current_user` and [flask_stateless_auth](https://github.com/omarryhan/flask-stateless-auth/blob/master/flask_stateless_auth/__init__.py) stores the `current_stateless_user` on the request context stack.

```
from flask import request
from flask_stateless_auth import current_stateless_user

with app.test_client() as c:
  test_path = '/resource_for_authenticated_users'
  c.get(test_path)
  assert request.path == test_url
  assert flask.session is not None # You can also access the session context local from here
  assert current_stateless_user is not None
```

If this was called without the `test_client()` context manager, it would throw a runtime error for trying to access the request local context after the `_request_ctx_stack` has been popped. Also, `current_stateless_user` would return `None`

### App Context

`app.app_context()`

Similarly, you can access variables that are stored on the [app context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/) via the `app.app_context()` context manager, as such:

```
from my_app.db import db # db connections are commonly stored on the `_app_ctx_stack`

with app.app_context():
  db.create_tables()
  assert db.session
  assert db.query.MyTable.all()
```

You can also access [app context global variable](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data)
(typically used to store app related global variables
that are not be used across multiple requests like the
`session` global)

```
with app.app_context():
  assert g.my_global_app_var
```

### Test Request Context

`test_request_context()`

Then you have the `app.test_request_context()` context manager which is used to activate a request context temporarily. This is best explained by the [official docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#other-testing-tricks).

### Session Transaction Context

`app.test_client().session_transaction()`

Finally, there's the `session_transaction()` context manager. This is typically used to modify a session object. This should be nested in an `app.test_client()`.

When the `__exit__()` method is called, the session is safely stored.

example from [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#accessing-and-modifying-sessions):

```
with app.test_client() as c:
     with c.session_transaction() as sess:
         sess['a_key'] = 'a value'

    # once this is reached the session was stored
```

Comment: Can you also provide some resources for that (helpful links, official docs, whatever)?

Comment: Done. I cited Flask's testing docs, with the part that's relevant to my answer hashbanged. There are also lots of other useful context managers, like: `session_transaction`, `app_context` and `test_request_context`.

Answer (score 2):

test_client is already prebuilt into flask, this makes it easier for people to quickly test their programs. Both the requests utility and test_client server the same functionality, so the usage is just based on personal preference.